# Multiple jQuery sliders with fixed value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to make to sliders, that got a fixed maximum of 100.

So if `#slider_1` rises to 72, `#slider_2` automaticly turns in to 28.
The script is for setting up the width of `#right` and `#left`.

Right now i got following:

```
                $("#width-r").slider({
                slide: function(event, ui) {
                    var other = $("#width-l");
                    var avi  = 100 - $("#width-r").slider("value");
                    var iva  = 100 - avi;
                    if(other.slider("value") >= avi){
                        other.slider("value", avi);
                    }else{
                        other.slider("value", iva);
                    }
                    if(other.slider("value") == ui.value){
                        var total = 100 - ui.value;
                        other.slider("value", total);
                    }
                    $("#width-r-t").text($("#width-r").slider("value"));
                    $("#width-l-t").text($("#width-l").slider("value"));
                }
            });
            $("#width-l").slider({
                slide: function(event, ui) {
                    var other = $("#width-r");
                    var avi  = 100 - $("#width-l").slider("value");
                    var iva  = 100 - avi;
                    if(other.slider("value") >= avi){
                        other.slider("value", avi);
                    }else{
                        other.slider("value", iva);
                    }
                    if(other.slider("value") == ui.value){
                        var total = 100 - ui.value;
                        other.slider("value", total);
                    }
                    $("#width-r-t").text($("#width-r").slider("value"));
                    $("#width-l-t").text($("#width-l").slider("value"));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. I have created a JsFiddle with the whole response: http://jsfiddle.net/YstM5/5/.

Basically, you should first initialize your sliders using the `value` field and you have to add a pair of lines in your `slide` method:

```
var max = 100; //maximum value for the two sliders
var initLeft = 50; //initial value for the left slider

$("#right").slider({
 max: max,
 min: 0,
 value: max - initLeft,
 slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $("#left").slider('option','value', max- ui.value);         
 }
 //other slide options here ...
});

$("#left").slider({
 max: max,
 min: 0,
 value: initLeft,
 slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $("#right").slider('option','value', max- ui.value);         
 }
 //other slide options here ...
});
```

It works!